# DllImport with .a file for iOS in MAUI

Tags: ios, .net, maui

I'm trying to add iOS support in [my library](https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi). In the library I use functions from native binaries via `DllImport` attributes. So for example:

```
[DllImport("libraryname")]
private static extern int Foo();
```

It works without any problems on Windows (via *libraryname.dll*) and macOS (via *libraryname.dylib*). From what I've learned from [the discussion](https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi/discussions/235) with the library user, we need .a file for iOS. The user has prepared a simple test MAUI solution: [Testify.zip](https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi/files/10420219/Testify.zip). In the *MainPage.xaml.cs* we have this declaration:

```
[DllImport("fat.a", ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int Foo();
```

*fat.a* has been built from this simple C code:

```
int Foo() { return 234; }
```

Here you can get the file: [fat.zip](https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi/files/10393008/fat.zip). The build process:

```
xcrun --sdk iphoneos --verbose clang -c code.c -o code_arm64.o -arch arm64
ar -rv code_arm64.a code_arm64.o

xcrun --sdk iphoneos --verbose clang -c code.c -o code_x86_64.o -arch x86_64
ar -rv code_x86_64.a code_x86_64.o

lipo code_x86_64.a code_arm64.a -output fat.a -create
lipo -info fat.a
```

Also the file is put to the *Resources/Raw* folder with `Copy to Output Directory` set to `Copy always`. We see the file in proper place in the built package on a target device or iOS simulator. But calling `Foo` we get the exception in runtime: **System.DllNotFoundException: fat.a**. Please see [this comment](https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi/discussions/235#discussioncomment-4682362) for more details.

So the question is how to use `DllImport` with native binaries for iOS in a MAUI project? Is it possible at all?

Comment: You could refer to [Referencing Native Libraries in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/native-interop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in [this comment](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12675#issuecomment-1383635990) I got an answer:

1. `"__Internal"` must be used in `DllImport` attributes.
2. Following element must be added to the csproj file:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <NativeReference Include="path/to/fat.a" Kind="Static" />
</ItemGroup>
```